# LINQ query in C# using group and join

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write the following SQL query in LINQ C# but am not able to get hold of the columns after the group clause.

SQL query

```
/*get the number of questions by subject*/

select b.SubjectID, b.SubjectName, count(*) AS count 
from QuestionsTable a, SubjectTable b
where a.SubjectID is not null AND a.SubjectID = b.SubjectID
GROUP BY a.SubjectID
```

LINQ Query

```
var result =(from a in db1.QuestionsTables
             join b in db1.SubjectTables 
             on a.SubjectID equals b.SubjectID
             where a.SubjectID != null
             group a by a.SubjectID  into g
             select new { a.QuestionID, a.SubjectID, b.SubjectName
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you sure your SQL query is correct? I don't think it is because `SubjectName` is neither present in group by clause nor in any aggregate function.

Comment: yes, the SQL query is correct. It is returning the expected results

Comment: Are you using `SQL Server`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SQL wouldn't be executed correctly cause you query groups by `a.Subject.ID`, but selects `b.SubjectID`, and `b.SubjectName`. Usually you should also include single selected fields to `GROUP BY` list.

(As far as I know, some SQL servers can process **functional dependent fields**, so they could process your query. But in general it's wrong).

So your working query should be:

```
SELECT b.SubjectID, b.SubjectName, COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM QuestionsTable a, SubjectTable b
WHERE a.SubjectID is not null AND a.SubjectID = b.SubjectID
GROUP BY b.SubjectID, b.SubjectName
```

And your LINQ should be

```
from a in db.QuestionsTable
join b in db.SubjectTable
  on a.SubjectId equals b.SubjectId
where a.SubjectId != null
group b by new { b.SubjectId, b.SubjectName } into g
select new { g.Key.SubjectId, g.Key.SubjectName, g.Count() }
```

Comment: @RahulSingh Updated. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about  functional dependent fields, Mark.

Answer (score 0):

Although it could be made the way you asked, the same result can be obtained in much simpler natural way, not involving grouping at all, like this

```
// get the number of questions by subject
var result =
    (from s in db1.SubjectTables
     select new
     { 
         s.SubjectID,
         s.SubjectName,
         Count = db1.QuestionsTables.Count(q => q.SubjectID == s.SubjectID)
     }).ToList();
```

**Update:** Regardless of downvotes, I strongly believe this is the right way to solve this particular problem - simple and natural. Why group something that is already grouped (by primary key).

Comment: This will almost certainly execute a query for *every row in the table* resulting in extremely poor performance.

Comment: @Corey That might have been true a long time ago - nowadays database query optimizers process subqueries very efficiently, in fact may turn them into a join when needed. In this particular case most probably a simple index range seek will be used.